# preg_replace round internal value of mapped value

Tags: php

I have a preg_replace firing like this:

```
echo preg_replace('/(.*?)(?:\()(.*?)(?:\))/', '$1<div class="parenthesis">($2)</div>', $data['display']);
```

I need to round the variable `$2`

I tried this:

```
echo preg_replace('/(.*?)(?:\()(.*?)(?:\))/', '$1<div class="parenthesis">('.round($2).')</div>', $data['display']);
```

But it returned a syntax error, i'm not very familiar with preg_replace and am not sure how to get specific in the area I need to round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for that. It lets you define a callback that gets all matches passed to it. You can then manipulate them as you please before building the new string.

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/(.*?)(?:\()(.*?)(?:\))/', function($matches) {

    return $matches[0] . '<div class="parenthesis">' . round($matches[1]) . '</div>';

}, $data['display']);
```

Comment: I suggest you use a different variable than the array you're processing, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Barmar - Good point. I'm a bit to fast for my own good, sometimes. Good catch on the mismatched quotes, as well!

Comment: That was easy because of the syntax highlighting.

Comment: I get this error message:  `Object of class Closure could not be converted to string`

Comment: @Jordash - omg... my bad... I told you to use preg_replace_callback(), but my example used preg_replace(). Sry! I have updated my answerso test again. I'll take that as a sign that it's time to hit the sack...